# Change on code size when using far pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, 68hc12

I work in the department of a software company that deals mainly in automotive network design. We write network protocol stacks in C, mainly. Recently, I was assigned a project which required the use of Freescale's HC12 controller. Originally written protocol stack supported use of unbanked RAM and both banked and unbanked flash. In the project assigned to me, the customer requires use of banked RAM instead of unbanked RAM (the reason is unknown to me). As I worked on the development of this project, I realised I could use far pointers to access (read/write) the banked RAM.

**My question is**: when I used the far pointers to access banked RAM, my library code size increased as much as 10kbytes. Is this normal? In the reference manual of the compiler I am using (codewarrior), the size of a far pointer is mentioned to be 3 bytes as opposed to a normal pointer which has a size of 2 bytes. Can this 1 extra byte really cause so much difference in code size? Is there any other way which would not include the use of far pointers where I can still access banked RAM?

Any helpful answers to my queries would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use the linker map file and the intermediate assembly files to figure out what is going on

Comment: Increasing "*as much as 10kbytes*" is a meaningless statistic without knowing the original size.  That would be insignificant if it were 1Mb, but truly surprising if it were 10kb.  You should express the increase as a proportion or percentage.  Moreover any increase would depend upon teh extent to which the original code used pointers in the first place.

Comment: @Clifford Originally, the code size was ~30kbytes. After using far pointers, the size increased to a little over 40kbytes. The original code consists of ~100 (guestimated) 8 bit pointers (including local pointers, pointers as function parameters, pointers inside structures, pointers used in macros etc.).

Comment: @Anas : You should update the question rather then put relevant information in a comment.  My point about pointer usage was just to point out that it is not possible to determine whether it is "normal" because code and coding practice vary; however it was also not about the *number* of pointers, but the density of pointer access and manipulation - one pointer accessed in 20 locations would be little different that 20 pointers accessed in one location each.  So again it is a useless metric, but I was not asking for a metric, just saying that it depends on the nature of the code in question.

Comment: @Clifford I apologize, I misunderstood your previous comment. From your new comment, I have another query, if you wouldn't mind. Can you elaborate on "one pointer accessed in 20 locations would be little different that 20 pointers accessed in one location each". How exactly would they be different?

Comment: @AnasImtiaz : "little different" meaning no significant difference in code size.  Native pointers (i,e,  those directly supported by the hardware) on HC12 are 16 bit. To dereference a far pointer the compiler has to generate code to first select the 64kb page, then dereference the real 16 bit address.  The code to do that 20 times for one pointer is probably no larger or smaller than that to do it on 20 different pointers.

Comment: ... The point being that the code size overhead of far pointers is not about the storage of the pointers (and therefore the number of pointers) - that is not in the code - it is about the code required to manipulate the non-native pointers.  I suggest that you look at the assembly code generated by your compiler (by requesting assembler listing output or through disassembly or via the debugger), and also the change in the link map (output by the linker) to see how the code differs and exactly what parts of the code are affected or what is added.

Comment: Create a simple piece of code with some simple pointer manipulation, perhaps instantiate and initialise a pointer, assign the pointer the address of a symbol, increment the pointer, dereference the pointer.  Do that with far and near pointers and observe the differences as above.  This will be much clearer than analysing your whole project.

Comment: @Clifford : Thanks for clearing that up. I will try this to observe how different types of pointers behave.

Answer (score 2):

Originally, banked memory on the HCS12 was only used for the program code in flash, in which case you won't notice a big difference in program size. The only difference will be that subroutine calls will need to use the banked memory instructions (CALL, RTC rather than JMP, RTS), that need a few bytes more of program memory per function call.

Then later on they released devices that had both banked flash and banked RAM (some of the HCS12X etc). RAM is obviously intended for data, not program memory.

The problem is that HCS12 is a 16 bit CPU, so it can't easily handle 24 bit data pointers. Meaning that all such code handling data in banked memory will become rather inefficient: for each access (through a "far" pointer etc), it will have to set up the page register which represent the upper 8 bits of the 24 bit address. Once that is done, it can read/write data to the 16 bit part of the address, with normal instructions, and the hardware will map it to the correct page. And once that is done, the program must also restore the page register.

It is quite possible that the compiler isn't able to optimize accesses to paged data well - in theory you could set the page register and then access all data in that page, before you need to restore it. But at compile-time, the compiler might not be able to know where exactly a variable will be allocated.

You can quite easily see what code that is actually generated by using Codewarrior's disassembler. Also note that Codewarrior has always been rather dysfunctional when it comes to optimizations: it is never quite clear which optimizations that have to be explicitly enabled and which ones that are "built-in". Ensure that you actually have all relevant optimizations enabled.

Overall, avoid banked memory whenever possible. You can use non-banked memory model up to 64k memory. It's only when you go beyond that limit that you need paged memory. Perhaps this is why your customer requires it, they likely ran out of RAM.

Comment: The whole banked memory fiasco on 8 and 16 bit MCUs is one of the main reasons never to use them in new designs. I'd pick a 32 bit MCU just to get rid of this headache.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It cleared some things I was confused about. Unfortunately, I cannot add optimizations that are not mentioned by the customer. Although, I will definitely try this locally.
Also, the HC12 variant that I have to work on has two 16k unbanked flash regions and one 16k flash region that can be paged to up to 256 pages.

Comment: I agree that using banked memory is quite a hassle. I was finally able to successfully get banked RAM to work. However, banked flash is yet another challenge. I am restricted to not place library's core APIs in banked memory as it would cause compatibility issues but their size has grown so much that any additional code (such as an application that uses this library) cannot be placed in the two unbanked flash regions.
Reading the compiler manual, I found that I can use the far keyword with function definitions to access them when the code is placed in banked flash but that has yet to be tested

Comment: @AnasImtiaz Moving code there is much easier than using banked data. The only consideration when writing code for that, is that you may or may not need to use `far` for function pointers (I think it depends on what memory model you have told Codewarrior to use internally). And of course, all ISRs must be in non-banked memory because the vector table is just 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not the pointer size that's necessarily growing, but the code that handles 'far' pointers (whatever exactly those are on the hc12)

The core itself only really supports 16 bit pointers, and this paging this is a bit of an add on and requires handholding by the program to make it work.

Good news is you're now paging, so 10k isn't horrific.